# Can I pass Username instead of Firstname + Lastname to shiny prox

Tags: keycloak, shinyproxy

I am using Shinyproxy with Keycloak and read the username with
`userName <- Sys.getenv("SHINYPROXY_USERNAME")`

Unfortunately I receive a concatenation of FirstName and LastName, which is not unique.

I would like to have the username in SHINYPROXY_USERNAME. Is this a Keycloak configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#single-sign-on-keycloak)

```
proxy.keycloak.name-attribute: name of the attribute to use as the user's name; 
     one of name (default, current behaviour), preferred_username, nickname or email
```

in the default keycloak token mapping `preferred_username` is the username of the keycloak user.

So set in your `application.yml`

```
 keycloak:
    ...
    name-attribute: preferred_username
```

If this does not work, you can always remove existing token mappers for `name` (a few token mappers a pre defined in client_scopes) and create a token mapper with the following config

- type: User Property
- property: username
- Token Claim Name: name
- ID/Access/User-Info: on

Now Keycloak tokens will contain a attribute `name` with the value of users `username`